# How to fix this 'Call to a member function row() on boolean' error?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to fetch some data from mysql. I am using codeigniter model and controller for this.

CI_model.php :

```
     public function getLastSale($id){


     $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * from sma_sales  desc limit 1 where customer_id = '$id' ");


    $result = $q->row();


    $res = array();
    $res['id'] = $result->id;
    $res['paid'] = $result->paid;


    return $res; 


}
```

CI_controller.php :

```
    $getLastData = $this->pos_model->getLastSale($customer_id);

    $sid = $getLastData['id'];

    $prepaid = $getLastData['paid'];
```

But this error is showing :

```
    An uncaught Exception was encountered
    Type: Error

    Message: Call to a member function row() on boolean
```

I am a beginner of codeigniter. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the query:

```
SELECT * from sma_sales  desc limit 1 where customer_id = '$id'
```

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * from sma_sales where customer_id = '$id' order by `sales_date` desc limit 1
```

You need to use the `ORDER BY` clause to do the sorting.

Also, make sure you escape the `$id` before including it inside the query. Have a look at [this](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html).

Another suggestion is that, you could check whether the `$result` is set or not. Because in case of errors, it would return NULL. Read more about it [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html).

Answer (score 4):

The error you are getting is because your `$result = $q->row()` is acting on a FALSE return from the `$db->query(...)` call.

*Call to a method on boolean*

I believe there is an error in your original SQL around this section `...sma_sales  desc limit...`

You need some sort of `ORDER BY` clause inbetween the `sma_sales` and `desc`.

You should also check that your returned query is valid..

```
if($q !== false)
{
    $result = $q->row();
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

*Or something like that*

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer, I don't know why no matter what I did it keeps persisting. Maybe it's a bug with Codeigniter but this is how I solved it.

since you need a row of results. use the `result()` method of the query object, then assess the first index of the array returned like this

```
result()[0]
```